# Adding WCF Services / Project Templates in Visual Studio Pro 2013?

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-2010

I'm very new to .NET and developing within VS, and I'm trying to make a few basic WCF Web Services for testing purposes. I'm running Visual Studio Profession 2013 on a Win 7 x64 computer that is also running Sharepoint 2010 Server.

I'm trying to go through the following tutorial:

https://jobrocol.wordpress.com/2012/06/03/custom-rest-wcf-service-in-sharepoint-2010/comment-page-1/

And already, I don't have the WCF Service that the author references in the third screenshot. I've done a ton of searching online for something to install, but I can't find anything definitive.

Here is what I see what I go to add a New Item and search Online for "wcf" - https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCCJG.png

Any advice on where I can download this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see it in my VS 2013 using `File` -> `New` -> `Website` and then choosing WCF like below:

[image]

Comment: Wow, was searching 'Online' instead of 'Installed'. Whoops! All good, thanks. http://i.imgur.com/sTZALBp.png